# How to refresh listctrl simultaneously when using setstringitem function

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets, listctrl

I'm so troubled by this problem:

I've create a `ListCtrl` object, a `TextCtrl` object, and a button. First I fill some data into the `ListCtrl` object, when I press the button, it will append some strings into `TextCtrl` object and use `SetStringItem` to modify `ListCtrl` object.

As you can see in the button function, I've added `time.sleep(2)` in each loop. When I've got is when the button is pressed, `TextCtrl` will be refreshed every time the strings is inserted, but `ListCtrl` just freeze until the LOOP IS FINISHED, then it will display the correct strings.

I want to know how to refresh the `ListCtrl` object as soon as `SetStringItem` is called.

Any help is deeply appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
import wx                                                                                                       
import sys                                                                                      
import time                                                                                     

class Frame(wx.Frame):                                                                          
    def __init__(self, parent):                                                                 
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, size=(450, 450))                                        
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)                                                             
        self.dl = wx.ListCtrl(self,-1,size=(300,100),style=wx.LC_REPORT)                        

        self.dl.InsertColumn(0, 'File')                                                         
        self.dl.InsertColumn(1, 'Progress')                                                     
        self.dl.InsertColumn(2, 'State')                                                        

        for row in range(3):                                                                    
            labels = [l+str(row) for l in "FILE PERCENT STATE".split()]                         
            # sys.maxint inserts at the end of the list                                         
            index = self.dl.InsertStringItem(sys.maxint, labels[0])                             
            self.dl.SetStringItem(index, 1, labels[1])                                          
            self.dl.SetStringItem(index, 2, labels[2])                                          

        self.Show(True)                                                                         

        button2 = wx.Button(self, label=u"test", pos=(15, 200), size=(60, 25))                  
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.test, button2)                                            
        self.text = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, pos=(80, 200), size=(200, 175), style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)
    def test(self,event):                                                                       
        for i in range(3):                                                                                                                                          
            self.dl.SetStringItem(i,1,"HELLO")                                                                                                            
            self.text.AppendText("HELLO")                                                       
            time.sleep(2)                                                                       

app = wx.App()                                                                                  
Frame(None)                                                                                     
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that time.sleep blocks your GUI, what you will need to do to get the effect that you are trying for is:

On your button press add the first item & start a 2 second wx.Timer with an event handler/

In the event handler add the next string or if there are no more to add cancel the timer.

Answer (score 1):

I've changed my code to this, and it works, thanks steve

```
import wx
import sys
import time


class Frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, size=(450, 450))
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.dl = wx.ListCtrl(self,-1,size=(300,100),style=wx.LC_REPORT)

        self.dl.InsertColumn(0, 'File')
        self.dl.InsertColumn(1, 'Progress')
        self.dl.InsertColumn(2, 'State')

        for row in range(3):
            labels = [l+str(row) for l in "FILE PERCENT STATE".split()]
            # sys.maxint inserts at the end of the list
            index = self.dl.InsertStringItem(sys.maxint, labels[0])
            self.dl.SetStringItem(index, 1, labels[1])
            self.dl.SetStringItem(index, 2, labels[2])

        self.Show(True)

        self.timer = wx.Timer(self,-1)
        #self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.OnTimer, self.timer)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.test1, self.timer)
        button2 = wx.Button(self, label=u"test", pos=(15, 200), size=(60, 25))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.test, button2)
        self.text = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, pos=(80, 200), size=(200, 175), style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)
        self.z=0



    def test(self,event):
        self.timer.Start(3000)

    def test1(self,event):
        for i in range(1):
            self.dl.SetStringItem(self.z,1,"HELLO")
            self.text.AppendText("HELLO")
            self.z+=1           
            if self.z >2 :
               self.timer.Stop()  


app = wx.App()
Frame(None)
app.MainLoop()
```